# onclick not worked as expected with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is the sample code..if I comment out the script it will call server side function on button click. what will be the error in following code??

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
   <input type="checkbox" id="chb1" value="Hourly" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="chb2" value="Daily" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="chb3" value="Weekly" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="chb4" value="Monthly" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="chb5" value="Yearly" />

  <asp:Button Text="submit" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
</form>
<div></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var selectedcout = 0;

        var countChecked = function () {
            var n = $("input:checked").length;                
            $("div").text(n + (n === 1 ? "is" : "are") + "checked");
        };
        countChecked();

        $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);

</script>
```

Comment: @ARUN OP is running the JS after the DOM is created so they don't need a DOM ready handler

Comment: Rory McCrossan Okay, new to me

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="chb1" value="Hourly"  runat="server"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook to the `submit` event of the form, not the `click` of the submit button, so that you can stop the form from being submitted. Try this:

```
var selectedcout = 0;

var countChecked = function() {        
    var n = $("input:checked").length;                
    $("div").text(n + (n === 1 ? " is " : " are ") + "checked");
};

countChecked();

$('#form1').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the form submitting
    countChecked();
});
```

Comment: not working,,control not coming to backend function on button click

Comment: Well, no, it wouldn't. You can only have one or the other. You can either update the UI and stop the form, or send the form and then you can't update the UI. If you want both you need to use AJAX.